Youtube Data API : Captions: download error inquiry?
Youtube Data API :  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download?hl=ko
After oauth2.0 authentication, the Youtube Data API Caption Download API was called, but the following error occurred.
I would like to inquire whether it is possible to download other people's video captions using the Youtube Data API.
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.",
                "domain": "youtube.caption",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "location": "id",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I am asking this question because I think a permission error occurred while trying to download someone else's YouTube Caption.
If possible, we would like to ask if there is an option among the YouTube video information that can be referenced.
For reference, the caption of the YouTube video is true and the information obtained from oauth permissions "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner" Viewed.

You cannot download other people's video captions using the Youtube Data API - if you don't have permissions over those account(s). You have to use another way(s) to download the captions.
